# The page URL key contains capital letters or disallowed symbols.";i:1;s:986:"

Tags: reports, ee-1.13, debugging

## `0 /home/cel/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')`

Why is it an error in the core? I've never edited anything in the core? This error completely confuses me... any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
if ($result) {
                    $this->_setResourceVersion($actionType, $file['toVersion']);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($e, true));
                throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Error in file: "%s" - %s', $fileName, $e->getMessage()));
            }
            $version = $file['toVersion'];
            $this->getConnection()->allowDdlCache();
        }
        self::$_hadUpdates = true;
        return $version;
    }
```

Comment: What process are you doing when you get this error? Its tough to help without much detail...

Comment: It is likely that something in custom code or an extension is calling a core function at some point. We would need a better stack trace for debugging to work. This is likely not a core issue but a messed call to a core file.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson uploading some modules to app/etc/modules

Comment: Wrap a try/catch around the lines where the error is occurring and `var_dump($e)` and see if that shows anything telling. If it does not, turn off modules one at a time until it stops so that at least you determine which module the issue stems from. That will give you a decent starting point.

Comment: Btw, are you developing remotely or on a vm? I published a video recently which will show you how to use xdebug together with phpstorm. With that combination it should be a piece of cake to track it down to a specific line in a specific module.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson line 645 is this: throw Mage::exception. I added/posted it above in the original post too. Not sure where i would add the try catch around since it looks like a catch is being used already.. You could help me out with this.